# Obtener hora y minutos usando TimePicker

Tags: android, android-studio

Como puedo obtener (en String o int) una hora que me introduscan usando el TimePicker...GRACIAS

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que tienes hasta ahora?

Comment: Cual TimePicker estas usando? Que lenguaje o lib?

Comment: Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: @AndrysAdonisSantosDomínguez Android Studio no es un lenguaje de programación, es un entorno de desarrollo. Se pueden escribir aplicaciones en Android Studio en diferentes lenguajes de programación (parece que quieres Java en tu pregunta).

Comment: Si, si lo se...solo que me exprece mal, era en Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione asi me quedo el metodo onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_llamadas);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHora);
    final TimePicker timePicker= (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickerInicio);
     boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActHora);
     boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          int hora= timePicker.getCurrentHour();
          int min=timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
          textView.setText(String.valueOf(hora)+": "+String.valueOf(min));

         }
     });


}
```

Comment: Hola Andry para que esta respuesta sea de ayuda agrega que realiza este código, que cambio se tiene con respecto a la pregunta original. Revisa [answer]